# Launching 100 fibers, iterating in each fiber and incrementing a Ref

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

I want to do the following:

1. Create 100 fibers
2. In each fiber, loop 1000 times and increment my `Ref`
3. After each fiber has completed 1000 iterations, shutdown the fiber
4. Before exiting the program, output the current value of the Ref.

   ```
   object Fibers extends IOApp.Simple {

      val program =
        for {
          ref <- Ref.of[IO, Int](0)
          total <- ref.get
          _ <- IO(println(s"ref total is: ${total}"))
        } yield ()

      override def run: IO[Unit] = program

    }
   ```

I also want to time how long this takes to complete (in milliseconds)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code you want.

```scala
object Fibers extends IOApp.Simple {
  private def logic(ref: Ref[IO, Int], nFibers: Int, nIterations: Int): IO[Unit] =
    List.range(start = 0, end = nFibers).parTraverse_ { _ =>
      List.range(start = 0, end = nIterations).traverse_ { _ =>
        ref.update(_ + 1)
      }
    }

  override final val run: IO[Unit] =
    IO.ref(0).flatTap { ref =>
      logic(ref, nFibers = 100, nIterations = 1000)
    } flatMap { ref =>
      ref.get.flatMap { total =>
        IO.println(s"Total is: ${total}")
      }
    }
}
```

Now, for benchmarking it please refer to a proper benchmarking tool.